# Linq Group selection

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to filter these results to only show the first and last row from each group. I've tried a couple of approaches with no luck. Below is the Linq query and the results.

Linq Query:

```
var currentAndHistoricalOnly = ViewCustomerGLAndPurchaseRecord
                               .Where(g=>g.CashierDate > new Datetime(2012,10,01)  
                                      &&  g.CashierDate < new DateTime(2012,12,01))
                               .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionId)   
                               .OrderByDescending(d => d.First().CashierDate);
```

[image: This is the result after executing the linq query]
Remember, I'm trying to keep the same grouping but filter(remove records) each group and take only the first record and the last record of each group.

So instead of:

**Group 1:**

1. Record 1
2. Record 2
3. Record 3
4. Record 4
5. Record 5

**Group 2:**

1. Record 1
2. Record 2
3. Record 3
4. Record 4

I need:

**Group 1:**

1. Record 1
2. Record 5

**Group 2:**

1. Record 1
2. Record 4

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var currentAndHistoricalOnly = ViewCustomerGLAndPurchaseRecord
                                 .Where(g=>g.CashierDate > new DateTime(2012,10,01) && g.CashierDate < new DateTime(2012,12,01)) 
                                 .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionId)
                                 .Select(g=> new {
                                     Last = g.OrderByDescending(c=>c.CashierDate).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     First = g.OrderBy(c=>c.CashierDate).FirstOrDefault(),
                                 })
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var list = ViewCustomerGLAndPurchaseRecord
           .Where(g=>g.CashierDate > new DateTime(2012,10,01) 
                  && g.CashierDate < new DateTime(2012,12,01)) 
           .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionId)
           .OrderByDescending(d => d.First().CashierDate)
           .Select(d =>  
           {
                var result = new List<ViewCustomerGLAndPurchaseRecord>();
                result.Add(d.FirstOrDefault());
                result.Add(d.LastOrDefault());
                return result;
           });
```

If you are using Entity Framework, Use **[AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** before select.

Hope this will help !!